# Why not use a sync method instead of await Async task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Async method:

```
public void Main(){
    await Asynctask1;
    DoSomething();
}

public async Task AsyncTask1(){
    //Async logic here
}
```

Sync method:

```
public void Main(){
    SyncMethod1();
    DoSomething();
}
```

I think I'm missing something here. Assuming that `SyncMethod1()` and `Asynctask1()` both do the same thing, aren't these 2 constructs in the end the same result, namely that `DoSomething()` doesn't start until the method before finishes?

Comment: The main different that AsyncTask1 will not block the UI--> important here NOT BLOCK and this does not means it will be run in another thread! if you want to run it in another thread then you have to use TASK. shall I post this as answer?

Comment: Not really the same. The MSDN has a pretty good explanation of the difference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: @TiesonT. you have right because the are handled diffrently in compiler we can not say they are same I have updated my comment.

Comment: Short answer would be: you use `async` when you need to run code *asynchronously*. For more info @TiesonT. link is a very good one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> namely that DoSomething() doesn't start until the method before finishes?

There's a difference between *asynchrony* and *sequential*. When you always `await` your asynchronous methods immediately, you end up with asynchronous sequential code, which at first glance does appear to behave similarly to synchronous sequential code. (On a side note, this similarity is the entire point of the `async`/`await` keywords). However, there's one important difference.

Let's say the operation is some I/O thing, like getting an HTTP resource. `SyncMethod1` will do the HTTP get synchronously; that is, it sends out the HTTP request and then *blocks the thread* until it gets the HTTP response. `AsyncTask1` will do the HTTP get asynchronously; that is, it sends out the HTTP request and then returns an incomplete `Task`. Later, when the HTTP request comes in, the `AsyncTask1` method will resume and complete the returned `Task`, and the code after the `await` is run (i.e., `DoSomething`).

The asynchronous way is more complicated but has one key advantage: it does not block a thread. So, UI threads are freed to enable a responsive UI and ASP.NET threads are freed to handle other requests.

I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that may help as you learn.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: It's not possible to have `await` in a synchronous method. The code in the question is missing an `async` on the first `Main`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you have outlined there is no practical difference as you immeadiately wait for the asynchronous method to complete before moving on to the next.

However, if you restructured your code something like this you might realize the power of asynchronous programming:

```
public async void Main() {
    Task performTask = AsyncTask1();
    //This method can continue without having to wait for AsyncTask1 to complete
    DoSomething();
    //Here we await the AsyncTask1 because perhaps other code further 
    //down is depending on it
    await performTask;
}
```